# With how may ways can the people get out of the elevator,if they are not distinguishable

Tags: combinations

There is an elevator with 8 people and 5 floors.With how may ways can these 8 people get out of the elevator,if we consider that they are not distinguishable?Which formula can I use to find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is the same as the following question :

Find the number of sets of $(a,b,c,d,e)\ (a,b,c,d,e\in\mathbb Z)$ such that
$$a+b+c+d+e=8.$$

The answer is 
$$\frac{12!}{4!8!}=\binom{12}{4}=495.$$

Imagine you have 8 circles and 4 short lines, and arrange them in a row. Then, count the number of balls in each section divided by lines.

For example, the following represents we have $(a,b,c,d,e)=(2,2,0,1,3).$ And we can think this as that $2$ people get out of the elevator on the 1st floor, $2$ people on 2nd floor...
$$\circ\circ|\circ\circ\ ||\circ|\circ\circ\circ$$

I hope this helps.

Comment: I understand...and,is there also an other way to calculate it?

Comment: What do you mean? Other way to calculate what? Your original question? or the example which I wrote?

Comment: My original question..I understood your previous post,but I wanted to know if there is also an other way to find the number of ways the 8 people get out of the elevator.

Comment: Well, I suspect you don't understand my example well. My example is the same question as yours. Only difference is that I used circles and lines. Imagine that circles mean people, lines mean each floor.

Comment: I understood your example..the general formula we get from this is $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ .So,is there not an other way of thinking that could help me solve the exercise?

Comment: $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, isn't? I don't know other ways though I don't know what kind of answers you want. Again, any other solution will be the same as mine, because mine is the same as yours.

Comment: You are welcome!